# How to return data in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, function, typescript, return-type

How to create a Typescript method with return type as **boolean** ?

I have tried the following code. But, it is not returning the value `true`.

```
 boolean function1(){
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Be more specific, paste some code if possible.

Comment: There is nothing special in Angular for function, you need basic JS to write function , Angular doesn't provide anything special in it !!

Comment: How did you know that it was not returning? What did you check?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public function1(): boolean {
           return true;
}
```

I am strongly recommend you to go throw this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Write function like below :

```
function1() : boolean {
 return true;
}
```

you can use public or private before function1 word also.